# What is this な? 「変態」ってな

Tags: meaning, particles, ambiguity, interpretation, particle-な

> （ナオト） お前のパンツ買うの忘れた。
> （真由）　 それぐらい ちゃんと持ってきてます。 変態。
> （ナオト） お前 「変態」**ってな**…。([source](https://a-haha.hatenadiary.org/entry/20151017/p1))

> （桐乃）　あんたが沙織とこそこそ仲よくなったりしたから、ややこしいことになったんじゃない
> （京介）　っていうか、興味津々じゃねえか！
> （桐乃）　うるさい！あんたこそ、何よ、あやせ見て デレーっとして。人の親友をあんな目で見んな！変態！
> （京介）　お前、変態**ってな**

I see two possibilities:

1. 禁止する意味の終助詞。「お前、変態って言うな！」
2. 詠嘆を表す間投助詞。「お前、変態って言ったな！」

Answer (score 2):

This な is a sentence-end particle similar to さ or ね. It's is nothing more than a slight "oh" or "come on".

(っ)てな(ぁ) also can be a contraction of というのは (e.g., 変態てなぁお前のことだ) in *shitamachi* speech, but this is not the case as long as てな is followed by nothing.

Comment: So my second guess? 「変態って言ってくれたな」

Comment: @EddieKal Hmm... I'm not sure if it's really for 詠嘆... I feel this is somewhere between a meaningless filler and an exclamatory particle. It's definitely not for 禁止, though.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the problem might be that you are not familiar with or failing to recognize the particular use of 「って」 in these dialogues.

The function of「って」 in question here is that of picking up on something someone has said or done as something you find remarkable, shocking, offensive, disturbing, funny, or otherwise mention-worthy.

Example 1

> A：こいつ馬鹿みたいに飲んでてベロベロなんですよ
> B：真っ昼間から酒って・・・

(Here B is expressing their shock or 「呆れ」 at broad-daylight hearty drinking)

Example 2

> A：あのクソジジイ、ガン飛ばしてきやがった
> B：「クソジジイ」って・・・

(Here B is implying that A's use of the word 「クソジジイ」 is out of line.)

What I think is the closest thing to a description of the 「な」 in the cases at hand that I could find in a dictionary is this (courtesy of [デジタル大辞泉](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%AA/#jn-162229)):

> ［間助］文末や、文中の種々の切れ目に用いる。語勢を添えて、自分の言葉を相手に納得させようとする気持ちを表す。「あの店はな、品物がいいんだ」「彼な、来られないんだって」

My understanding of this type of 「な」 is that it is something you use to make sure your intended listener knows that your speech is addressed to them.

(I guess this is what is called「(聞き手への)働きかけ」 in linguistic discourse on, including, but not limited to, 終助詞 and 間投助詞.)

So, in both of your two dialogues,「変態ってな」 does not express a command not to call them "変態" (as「お前、変態って言うな！」 does) or the angry accusation of「お前、変態って言ったな！」. Rather, the speaker is picking up on the utterance of "変態", implying that they find it shocking, and in effect protesting (rather meekly) to the other person, at being called such.